# Firing order issue

Tags: c#, .net, mvp

I have an issue where some a line of code is firing before it should do (in my eyes, at least). The code in question is Line 3 of the code in the button click event below. And i cannot figure out why this is.

Line 2 of the code sends the event to the associated Presenter, and before the code in the presenter event has finished executing, Line 3 gets fired.

Maybe I am missing something obvious, but cannot think what.

```
private void btnGetData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.statusIndicatorLabel.Text = "Processing...";
    this.GetDataButtonClick(this, e);
    this.statusIndicatorLabel.Text = "Processing complete";
}
```

What is it I am missing here?

**Edit:**

The definition of GetDataButtonClick is:

```
private async void _mainView_GetDataButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: We need to see the definition of `GetDataButtonClick`. If `GetDataButtonClick` is an `async`/`Task` method then it won't block and line 3 will be called sooner than you expect.

Comment: Yes GetDataButtonClick is delegated to an async task in the presenter. The definition is below: private async void _mainView_GetDataButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: @Daniel code in the comments does not help anyone, edit your question so its got everything we need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment you said that `GetDataButtonClick` is an `async Task` method. In which case:

1. Rename `GetDataButtonClick` to `GetDataButtonClickAsync` because in .NET methods that work asynchronously and express their return value as a `Task` should have the method name suffix `Async` to make it clear to humans reading your code that it is a non-blocking TPL method.
2. Change `btnGetData_Click` to an `async void` method. Note that event-handlers are (generally) the *only* time it is acceptable to have `async void` instead of `async Task`. This also means that you should not call `btnGetData_Click` directly: only ever use it as a fire-and-forget invocation instead because the caller has no information about the eventual completion of the method (and you can't use `async Task` because the `System.EventHandler` requires a return type of `void`.
3. Add an `await`, but do not add `.ConfigureAwait(false)` because execution should resume on the UI thread after `GetDataButtonClick` completes.

Like so:

```
private async void btnGetData_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.statusIndicatorLabel.Text = "Processing...";
    await this.GetDataButtonClickAsync(this, e);
    this.statusIndicatorLabel.Text = "Processing complete";
}
```

Comment: That's worked like a charm. Thank you very much for the detailed explanation and example.